# Why do files downloaded from Google drive fail md5?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a backup of a SQLite3 database from Google Drive through python. The file downloads, but always fails an md5 checksum and never shows any of the data in my database. The row headings of my database are viewable in the downloaded file and a very small file (~3kb) will download correctly. If I download it through a browser, it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
drive_service = GoogleAPI.build('drive', 'v2', auth)
fileID = "ID STRING"

drive_file = drive_service.files().get(fileId=fileID).execute()
download_url = drive_file.get('downloadUrl')
name = drive_file.get('originalFilename')
name += ".db"

resp, content = drive_service._http.request(download_url)
if resp.status == 200:
    print 'Status: %s' % resp

with open(name, "w") as file:
    file.write(content)
if not file.closed:
    file.close()
print "done"
```

Comment: Are you running this script on a Windows operating system by any chance? Then you'd need to open the file in binary mode for writing: `open(name, "wb") as file_`

Comment: I was testing in a Windows environment. This cleared it up, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not opening the file in binary mode.

> open the file in binary mode for writing: open(name, "wb") as file_

Thanks Lukas